# How to sign using new keyvault client from azure.security.keyvault

Tags: c#, azure, azure-keyvault, sign

I recently started to replace the old Azure KeyVault client from the `Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault`namespace with the newer one in `Azure.Security.KeyVault`.

This works without any issues when getting secrets and certificates, but I am not sure how to sign anymore

How do I sign using the new keyvault client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check Azure SDK Azure.Security.KeyVault.Keys package on [github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/keyvault/Azure.Security.KeyVault.Keys/samples/Sample5_SignVerify.md)?

Example code from that source:

```
SignResult rsaSignDataResult = rsaCryptoClient.SignData(SignatureAlgorithm.RS256, data);
Debug.WriteLine($"Signed data using the algorithm {rsaSignDataResult.Algorithm}, with key {rsaSignDataResult.KeyId}. The resulting signature is {Convert.ToBase64String(rsaSignDataResult.Signature)}");
```

Comment: I have not, I have no keys in KeyVault so I didn't think I'd need the client for that.

Answer (score 1):

For azure key vault, we need to [create a signature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/sign/sign) from a digest **using the specified key**.

So, you could refer to the below code to sign some arbitrary data and verify the signatures using the CryptographyClient with both the EC and RSA keys we created.

```
byte[] digest = null;

using (HashAlgorithm hashAlgo = SHA256.Create())
{
    digest = hashAlgo.ComputeHash(data);
}

SignResult rsaSignResult = rsaCryptoClient.Sign(SignatureAlgorithm.RS256, digest);
```

If you want to sign certificate you could refer to this [article](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/sdk/keyvault/Azure.Security.KeyVault.Certificates).